# Calculate working hours between 2 time(0) columns

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Please check the screenshot, So you understand the columns and my needs.

[image]

My questions are :

**1)**
I have 2 columns , from_time , till_time. 
I need to calculate the difference so i can report the hours.
Example : from_time=11:35, till_time=12:35 >> time_worked=01:00

How do i make the calculation, so i can make select , and report like "select total 'worked_hours' group by 'Can_bill'"

**2)** 
I have some procedure :

```
SELECT
       [ROW_ID]
      ,[User_Name]
      ,[Date]
      ,[From_Time]
      ,[Till_Time]
      ,[Customer_Name]
      ,[Product_Name]
      ,[Type_Of_Service]
      ,[Can_Bill]
      ,[Type_Impliment]
      ,[Notes]
  FROM [SG_Hours].[dbo].[Working_Hours_CheckIn]
Where User_Name = '@Login'
      And MONTH(Date) = MONTH(GetDate())
```

Now, I need to create the same thing, but instead of getting the latest month report , i need the user to select month , and then output him the report for the specific month. (It implemented on a BI application so i just need the code\procedure, and the UI will be implimented. )

Thanks a lot!!! You are the Best

Comment: Did you try `DateDiff` ?

Comment: No, This is not Datetime type case.

Comment: Thanks, would you please right the example ?

Comment: Your question needs clarification, provide sample data and a result expected .

Comment: Please, you can see the sample data on the screenshot in the top of the post. All i expect is to take this 2 time columns and calculate it to working_hours column , so i can report how many hours the user is worked , and select it by : totall hours worked today by 'Can_bill'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will gives `Time Worked` (Minutes) :

```
SELECT (CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(
                       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), till_time, 108),
                       ':',
                       ''
                    )
              )  - 
CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(
                       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), from_time, 108),
                       ':',
                       ''
                    )
              )   ) As time_worked FROM [SG_Hours].[dbo].[Working_Hours_CheckIn]
```

If you want to convert the minutes to `Time` you can do it as :

```
set @num = 1500000;  -- the resault of minutes            


select dateadd(hour, (@num / 1000000) % 100,
       dateadd(minute, (@num / 10000) % 100,
       dateadd(second, (@num / 100) % 100,
       dateadd(millisecond, (@num % 100) * 10, cast('00:00:00' as time ))))) As time_worked
```

Comment: thanks, it works. how do i convert it ? do i have to set a procedure and put the second part?

Comment: If that work for you , you can accept my answer , and you can simply add it to your query  or as procedure as you like.

Comment: Tohether it cant run, sorry.